# django sql translation

Tags: sql, django, models

I have 2 tables. They are joined by a foreign key relationship. In django, how do i do the equivalent of

```
select col1,col2,col3, table2.* from table1 join  table2 on table1.table1id  = table2.table2id
```

I am using `serializers.serialize` and as such `values()` does not work on the model

EDIT

Here are my 2 models i am using

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    FbookID = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name="facebookid",
        primary_key=True
    )

    Fname = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name="fname"
    )
    profilePic = models.CharField(
        max_length=256,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name="picture"
    )
    Sname = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=True,

    )
    faccesskey = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        blank=True,

    )
    userGender = models.CharField(
        max_length=15,
        default='MALE')

    joined = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True,
        verbose_name = "userjoinedsite"
    )
    last_active = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=True,
        verbose_name = "lastActiveOnSite"
    )

    #have to refer to other class in strings as this table is not created when this command is run
    last_loc = models.ForeignKey('user_LocLat',null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="EmailOfUser")


class user_LocLat(models.Model):

    locationID = models.AutoField(
        verbose_name="location",
        null= False,
        primary_key = True
    )
    FbookIDlat = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile')
    Date_of_loc = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True
    )
    loc = models.PointField(
        verbose_name="location",
        blank=False,
        null=False
    )
    speed = models.FloatField( verbose_name ='speedms',null=True)
```

I need to access `Fname,Sname,Gender, last_active, email` from `UserProfile` and `loc` and `speed` from  `User_latloc.` The main thing is i can not include `faccesskey`  in the return

Comment: please add your django models to question

Comment: Ive update my question to include the models,Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your sql don't have `where` clause, so to select all ocurrences:

```
user_loclat = user_LocLat.objects.all()
```

Then you can iterate and access to the fields, like:

```
for user_l in user_loclat:
    loc = user_l.loc
    Fname = user_l.FbookIDlat.Fname
    ...
```

Or you can use values():

```
users_data = user_LocLat.objects.all().values(loc, FbookDlat__Fname, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

when using django there is no need to use SQL directly (on some special cases you may need) but generally django orm is your best option:

for simplicity of your code change

```
FbookIDlat = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile')
```

to this:

```
FbookIDlat = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile', related_name='fbookidlats')
```

and remove this line:

```
last_loc = models.ForeignKey('user_LocLat',null=True)
```

when you create a foreign key django handles reverse call back

assume you want get info for a profile:

```
   profile = UserProfile.objects.get(FbookID='fbid')
   for fbookidlat in profile.fbookidlats.all():
       print(fbooidlat.speed)
```

PS-1: please read [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) it helps you write a cleaner code

PS-2: please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445649/is-it-ok-to-use-character-values-for-primary-keys) link