# Drawbacks of using nvarchar primary key in MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

For convienience I've changed my tables' primary keys to the `nvarchar` type. But now my views and controllers don't work in MVC.

If I manually add `[Key]` attribute to Id column which isn't a `PRIMARY KEY` will it work normally? How this change can hurt my application. What should I look out for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL primary key: integer vs varchar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162202/sql-primary-key-integer-vs-varchar)

Comment: "convenience" is not a valid reason to change the type of the primary key. I'd go back to that.

Comment: if your data is big, the performance will be a problem

Comment: What is a big database?