# Relational database design for photography website

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

I'm creating a database for a photography website and I want it to allow three main things -

Allow the owner/admin to create client accounts and credentials,
Specifying which photos should go into three different portfolio galleries on the site, and,
Displaying a unique client's photos (and only their photos!) to them when they log in.

**This is my first database design ever** - based on responses below, I've added that emphasis ;) and edited the design as below.

**IMAGES**
image_id,
filename,
description,
client_id,
date_uploaded,

**USERS/CLIENTS**
client_id,
client_name
username,
password,

**PORTFOLIO**
portfolio_id,
portfolio_name,

**PORTFOLIO_IMAGES**
id,
image_id,
portfolio_id,

Am I correct in thinking that the final id in PORTFOLIO_IMAGES would allow me to display one image in multiple galleries?
Thanks

Comment: Is a client himself a user or may there many users associated with the same client?

Answer (score 2):

As it is your first DB-Design and as you may have mentioned in the comments here is something essential missing: [ER-Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Er_diagram). This helps a lot understanding what's going on.

## ER-Diagram

[image]

**Synonyms**: User=Account, Image=Photo, Gallery=Portfolio
**Known Roles**: "Admin", "Client"
**Examples for Rights**: "Create Account", "Delete Account", "Watch images", "Add Gallery", "Remove Gallery", "Upload image", "Delete image", ...

## Table Design

**User**

- id
- name
- password

**Image**

- id
- user_id
- filename
- description
- upload_date

**Image_Gallery**

- image_id
- gallery_id

**Gallery**

- id
- name

---

**User_Role**

- user_id
- role_id

**User_Right**

- user_id
- right_id

**Role**

- id
- name

**Role_Right**

- role_id
- right_id

**Right**

- id
- name

You may want to remove all the things with `Right` if it is enough to separate user privileges by `Role`.

Comment: thanks for going to such lengths here. Your questions were right - to clarify, a User will only be related to one Client and vice-versa.
A Client will have many Images, but each Image will only have one Client. Hope this helps?

Comment: It helps much. I will update until it is clear if a client is really himself a user (aka account) or something else? Are clients users with a special role? 

I am wondering about this:

> Displaying a unique client's photos (and only **their** photos!) to them when they log in.

This `their` does not sound like User:Client to be 1:1. But maybe it's just because I do not understand it right.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not being clear, but yes, one 'user' = one 'client'. 
I.E. The 'Client' has a photoshoot, then they're given a 'Username' and password to login to the site, so they can see their photos.
There will be one or two seperate Admin accounts that will be already set-up that can create new 'Username/Password' for each 'Client'. Does that make sense? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. In this case "Client" will be a `Role` like "Admin" is a role, too. But they are all users. Roles are associated with Rights, i.e. the Role "Admin" will be associated with rights to manage accounts. I'll update ...

Answer (score 1):

1. Within the tables `images` and `users`, you will be referencing the clients id, not the name.
2. I would create a separate table for the galleries, as clients tend to have new wishes every three month. So you maybe need to add more galleries.

   - table "galleries"

     - id
     - name
   - table "image_is_in_gallery"

     - image_id
     - gallery_id
     - PRIMARY(image_id, gallery_id)

Comment: As I mentioned on the other answer, it would be equally valid to make the client name the primary key and drop the surrogate key. I abhor unnecessary surrogates when there are perfectly usable natural keys already on the entity.

Comment: 1) Yeah, I was kind of thinking this would make more sense, thank you :)

2) so, in "image_is_in_gallery" I can repeat image_id's and assign them different gallery_id's to specify which galleries they should appear in?

Comment: But if you do so, you need to make sure, the foreign key is set to CASCADE. That is necessary, if the client wants to be mentioned as "夏小万" instead of "[Xia Xiaowan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xia_Xiao_Wan)". You are also duplicating (maybe huge) data all over your tables, when [using VARCHAR as PRIMARY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144109/sql-server-normalization-tactic-varchar-vs-int-identity). @Sam Campsall Yes, but every image may occur only once per gallery.

Comment: @feeela - that's fine, that's what I'm after! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider normalization.

Assuming that usernames are unique - two people can't have the same username, come on - then you can eliminate "id" in the Users table in order to help prevent update/insert/delete anomalies (doing this would almost certainly put Users into BCNF, and likely DKNF - this is a good thing).

Clients is fine. What is the difference between Clients and Users, though? Really... seems similar to me.

Make sure that references are done using foreign key constraints, and I think that should be better.

EDIT:

Based on the new design, I have these suggestions:

Change Clients/Users into three tables:

```
  ClientNames
  - ClientID (PK)
  - ClientName

  ClientUsernames
  - ClientID (PK)
  - Username

  UsernamePasswords
  - Username (PK)
  - Password
```

This is safe and says that one Client/User has one name, one Client/User has one Username, and one Username has one Password. I don't see another good decomposition (in the sense that it's going to be in a tight normal form).

You can eliminate one of these tables by eliminating the synthetic "ClientID" key, if you want. There are disadvantages to this, and it may not be possible (some people do have the same name!).

The problem here is that it is likely that ClientID, ClientName, and UserName determine each other in a way that isn't amenable to stuffing them in the same table.

Comment: make ID an auto generate number and just put a unique index on username. If you get rid of the ID and use the user name as the PK, you'll get burned when someone gets married or divorced and wants to change their user name and you have a bunch of foreign keys.

Comment: @Patrick87. I had intended that Client_name was really client_ID, I just hadn't thought it through enough to be clear, so I think Username should be distinct from that?

Comment: @KM. I think my above comment makes this make sense - Client_name and ID combine to become Client_ID?

Comment: @KM: Still, this doesn't solve the problem of having non-normalized tables. While it's sometimes appropriate to ignore normalization, this doesn't seem like a great place. Perhaps there are other ways to normalize that avoid any problems you foresee.

Comment: @Sam: So what is the difference between Users and Clients? Just get rid of the Clients table. Also, as long as Clients/Users can have multiple Usernames, the rest is OK; otherwise, you'll need to do some non-dependency-preserving decompositions to make it robust. On second thought, if Username determines Password, you'll need a separate table for that, too... so ClientID would be associated with Username/Password pairs, the pairs existing in separate tables. Let me know if you'd like me to edit the answer to illustrate.

Comment: @Patrick. This is a fair question, and one that I can't really give a good answer to - hence the OP! I'm just going to edit it with suggestions here - let me know your thoughts...

Comment: @Patrick - Thanks for the edit - I think I now understand how doing it this way makes sense. Looking at this setup, it seems the seperate 'ClientNames' table could be extended to add other details also (address, tel no etc) which could be useful too? 
Really appreciate your time on this :)

Comment: Yeah, normalization brings with it a host of benefits: clean extensibility, reduced redundant information storage, automatic prevention of insert/update/delete anomalies, etc. Normalization is a complex subject, but you might consider studying it if you're going to be doing lots of DB design... in most environments where you have to design a system, there aren't really hard-and-fast measures of "goodness"; normalization provides an objective metric for determining how "good" the database design is.

Comment: Any pointers to a good normalization primer welcomed then! The book I'm using obviously didn't do a great job ;)
Thanks so much for all your help

Answer (score 0):

1. use client id instead of client_name on the images and users table
2. Add another table, portfolio with at least name and id columns
3. Add another table, portfolio_images with two columns, image_id and portfolio_id.  This will allow the feature mentioned by @Alex in the comments

**response to edit**
You can do the one image in multiple portfolios by querying PORTFOLIO_IMAGES and JOINing with images or portfolios as necessary.  For example, if you want to display the wedding portfolio (psuedo-code)

```
SELECT filename,... 
FROM images img
INNER JOIN portfolio_images pimg on img.image_id = portfolio_images.image_id
WHERE pimg.portfolio_id = <whatever the id is for wedding portfolio>
```

Comment: Agree w/ 1 and 2, but for 3, you'll need to add another table or an image will only be able to exist in one gallery.

Comment: Alternatively, he could drop the surrogate key and make client_name the primary key. This is what I would do.

Comment: He must already have a unique constraint on that column or he wouldn't have been able to make it a foreign key in the first place.

Comment: @Daniel Lyons Yes that is true, but it still doesn't help OPs client when they get a client with the same name as a past client.

Comment: If the OP is making the rows in this database himself, he's going to wind up giving the clients different names anyhow. If the clients are registering by themselves, then I agree with you, but that isn't always the case. Based on the design he presented, it sounds to me like this is going to be manually curated.

Comment: As I said, they'll be created by the site owner/admin

Comment: Would you guys consider giving me a fresh response to my edited post - I really appreciate your input.

Comment: @BioBuckyBall - OK, so I can set a command that'll cross reference the portfolio_ID and the image_ID's to display the required images - this is becoming clearer to me!
But the PORTFOLIO_IMAGES table will still need an ID column to create a unique key? Otherwise there's no unique value for each row?... 
Really appreciate your help :)